# Hiding member variables that should not be mutated in a base class which only allows const access so one can keep the assignment operator

Tags: c++, constants, base-class

I have a member variable that should never be changed from inside the class it's in, so it should be `const`, but I'd like to keep the assignment operator for that class.

So I came up with the idea to "hide" the member in a base class that only allows const access trough a getter:

```
class Base
{
public:

    Base(Settings settings) : mSettings(settings) {}

    const Settings&
    GetSettings() const { return mSettings; }

private:

    Settings mSettings;
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:

    Derived(Settings settings) : Base(settings) {}
 };
```

I can access the member trough the getter, can't accidentally change it and it seems better then a simple wrapper because a wrapper could still be overwritten trough it's own assignment operator.

Anyone see any problems or pitfalls with this? Any backdoor ways to modify the member anyway that would render the whole construct useless?

EDIT: To give a little more context about the use case.
The `Settings` are for a `Product` class. It includes things like the dimensions of the product. A product cannot resize itself, and I want to prevent accidentally doing so by somehow restricting access to the settings as const. However, it's fine for client code to make assignments `x = y //Product x now has the same properties as y`

Comment: If it's supposed to be `const` mark it `const` and write your own assignment operator.

Comment: What if the two classes Settings differ and you assign one to the other?

Comment: @PeteBecker Perhaps I wasn't clear. The class should never change it's own settings that it was given but client code should be able to assign instances with different settings to another.

Comment: @AnonMail Then the entire invariant that belongs with those settings is copied as a whole and that is fine.

Comment: @Unimportant in that case, it can't be const since you wouldn't be able to assign it.

Comment: @AnonMail : That's the problem the solution in the question tries to solve.

Comment: @Unimportant but it doesn't.  Try writing your assignment operator and you will see that's the case.

Comment: @AnonMail Could you please read the code more carefully. The `Settings` in the base class aren't `const`. The compiler generated assignment operator works fine.  I'm just wondering if there's pitfalls I'm overlooking/don't know about.

Comment: @Unimportant I think what you've done will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could still write:

```
void oops(Settings s) {*dynamic_cast<Base*>(this) = Base(s);}
```

But, honestly, good program design and good programming practices come side-by-side. I think you are safe enough: If someone goes this far to break your interface, there's something wrong with the programmers you're hiring. Access modifiers such as `private` and `protected` are not meant as a security feature: They are there to help you, a *good developer*<sup>TM</sup>, to avoid shooting yourself on the foot, and they do that by giving more information to the compiler (and yourself) on who is supposed to be accessing what information, so it can generate helpful error messages that are intended to prevent such errors.

In short: You're the boss here, and not the compiler. Express your intent clearly (as you have done already) and don't try to use interfaces in a way that they are obviously not meant to be used, and you'll be fine.

Comment: well, even though the train of thinking is good, technically that alone won't break it. Because polymorphism used in `oops` would only work if `Base` class had defined `virtual void oops(Settings s) {}` method, but it doesn't. Besides, even if (accidentally) the virtual base method was defined, there's an easy escape - define a Base class' `operator=` as deleted: `Base & operator=(const Base &) = delete;` and you'll be safe even by then.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't see what you mean: [There's no need for `Base` to define `oops`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18f68a15ef775d39), because there's no polymorphic behavior here: Just a simple cast. Also, defining `Base::operator=` as deleted is against the OP's requirements, because then `Derived::operator=` would also be deleted by default.

Comment: Yes, agree, if the Base/Derived classes would not be used as polymorphic, then it works. W.r.t. assignment operator, it's the really programming logic which dictates whether it's needed or not. Instead of deleting it, it could have been moved to `private`